# How does one implement a push service for a BlackBerry app?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-push

Can someone refer me to a good tutorial or starting point for implementing a push service for BlackBerry apps?
I've read about the basic idea of a push service.  I need some sample to code to start with.

Answer (score 5):

Look in the JDE folder, there is a sample folder where you can find a nice code sample.

It's called httppushdemo, and there is a samples\com\rim\samples\server\httppushdemo

for the server.