# Sample Push Service Client Application code : Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-push

There are two sides to a push application:

- Server push application
- Client push application (On Mobile)

I have implemented the server side application already, but I have not yet finished the client application.

Could anyone give me simple code for a client application using java please?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116699/how-does-one-implement-a-push-service-for-a-blackberry-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download the Push API from RIM (available on [this page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp)) there is a sample client application in source code included.